# JavaFX Get Koordinates from Toggle Button

Tags: java, javafx, components, togglebutton

I have a ToggleButton in JavaFX. I want to know on which Coordinate this ToggleButton is. Is there a Function that delivers this values like:

getCoordinates or something like that?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to know the position a) on screen, b) in the scene, c) in the parent node, use `Node`'s methods [localToScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScreen-double-double-), [localToScene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene-double-double-) or [localToParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParent-double-double-), respectively.

**Example**

To get the top left corner of your toggle button in the scene, do

```
Point2D pos = toggleButton.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for method getLayoutX, getLayoutY.